# I'm searching for a Data Table Template/Framework which is responsive

Tags: wordpress, web

I'm searching for a Website Template or Webframework in which I can easily important big datasets and present it in a representative way to visitors of my website. Does anybode have an idea what a sufficient theme is?

And good example of the website that I want to create is sofifa.com!

Answer (score 0):

Django is the best option! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/
It is written in Python, so it is easy to understand, it is secure and there are tons of ressources out there.
Here is in my opinion the best beginner tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ELCMngbM0E&list=PL-51WBLyFTg0omnamUjL1TCVov7yDTRng